# How to change recyclerview position on screen dynamically?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to put a cardview above a recyclerview list(cardview and recyclerview are seperate).  When swiping left the cardview and making it lost, recyclerview should be full screen but have no idea about how to do it. Do you know how to change recyclerview screen location if you understand what I mean? Thank you

[This is what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S8Qm.png)

Comment: Have you tried setting recyclerView height to match parent or fill parent?

Comment: It will be a lot easier if you also post your XML code here

Comment: **When swiping left the cardview and making it lost** are you doing it by visibility GONE or how ?

Comment: Jaswant Singh:  I put a picture maybe it can more clear now, thank you

Comment: if you answer the question I asked above , could solve your issue

Comment: Krishna Sharma: I will use a library for getting rid of the cardview , it is not my main problem. The main problem is changing recyclerview screen from partial to fullscreen when the cardview is gone, thank you

Comment: what are you doing to delete cardview from the view , share the code please. even if you share the layout will help

Comment: Planning to use Yalantis library for that, thanks. https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda-Android

Comment: adding a library for such a simple task is pure overkill. better define layout_weight... and then call `invalidate()` on the `RecylcerViews` parent when `CardView`'s swipe-away has completed.

Comment: that is a great idea Martin Zeitler. Putting recyclerview and cardview in a parent layout and setting the cardview layout weight to 0 when the swipe is occured will make the trick as you said. But I would use the library for swiping cardview, do you have a better solution also for that? Thanks a lot indeed

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to set the visibility `Visibility.GONE` for the `cardview` on swipe-away complete, accordingly your layout will get expanded automatically and RecyclerView acquire the available space.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a LinearLayout with using weights on child components.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

- Take `LinearLayout` as parent.
- Set `CardView` fixed height
- Set `RecyclerView` weight
- `Weight` makes a component to take available space.

**If you set `CardView` visibility gone then `RecyclerView` will take full screen.** If `CardView` is visible then `RecyclerView` will take available space.

**Output**

--------------CardView visible------------------------------------CardView visibility gone------------------------ 
[image]